# What is Mafalda’s surname?

Tags: harry-potter, character-identification, names

There exists a character that was cut from Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire (the book). Her name was Mafalda and she was a cousin to the Weasleys on Mrs Weasley’s side (the Prewetts).

Due to being on Mrs Weasley’s side of the family, lots of YouTube comments (the ones on HP Folklore’s video on Mafalda) claimed that Prewett is her last name, while others (like the HP Wiki) have stated that there’s no proof of that.

So what IS her surname?

Comment: Short of an answer from JKR, I don't think this is possible to answer. She was supposedly the child of Molly Weasley's second-cousin (a Squib), so his surname wouldn't necessarily be Prewett depending on exactly how they're related.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - Indeed. They're simply [too far apart](https://i1.wp.com/fh.familysearch.org/system/files/team/ait/images/blog/cousin-chart.jpg?w=736). If the great grandparents had a son and a daughter, and that daughter married and had a daughter and that daughter married, they could have had three entirely different sets of maiden names through three generations.

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20040803113633/http://www.jkrowling.com:80/textonly/extrastuff_view.cfm?id=3

Comment: Mafalda Hopkirk.

Comment: @Alex This is a different Mafalda

Comment: some leads mentioned here https://www.mugglenet.com/2020/08/the-weasley-family-tree-linking-minor-characters/